# Codeigniter: Display RAW query results

Tags: codeigniter, profiler

Is there a way to get the result of a query that was created with Active Record without using stuff like print_r() ?

I know about the [Profiler in Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) but I need something that also displays the output of the query, not only the query itself (as the profiler does).

Thanks!

Comment: Something like: SELECT * FROM cars will output:


+---------+------------------+
| id_car | licence plate |
+---------+------------------+
|     123 | SBX-08-YXG        |
+---------+------------------+

Comment: "Something like..." is not specific at all, when you say RAW results, you'd have to have some standard or example of RAW results that you are trying to emulate.  when you say RAW, do you mean the output of the `mysql` command line tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started to look into this and ended up extending the profiler class to also print the query result. Like jondavidjohn I am a little confused about what you really want, but hopefully this comes close. What you will have to do is to create a file called MY_Profiler.php in application/libraries and then paste the following code into it:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Profiler extends CI_Profiler
{
    protected function _compile_queries()
    {
        $dbs = array();

        // Let's determine which databases are currently connected to
        foreach (get_object_vars($this->CI) as $CI_object)
        {
            if (is_object($CI_object) && is_subclass_of(get_class($CI_object), 'CI_DB') )
            {
                $dbs[] = $CI_object;
            }
        }

        if (count($dbs) == 0)
        {
            $output  = "\n\n";
            $output .= '<fieldset id="ci_profiler_queries" style="border:1px solid #0000FF;padding:6px 10px 10px 10px;margin:20px 0 20px 0;background-color:#eee">';
            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= '<legend style="color:#0000FF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_queries').'&nbsp;&nbsp;</legend>';
            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= "\n\n<table style='border:none; width:100%;'>\n";
            $output .="<tr><td style='width:100%;color:#0000FF;font-weight:normal;background-color:#eee;padding:5px'>".$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_no_db')."</td></tr>\n";
            $output .= "</table>\n";
            $output .= "</fieldset>";

            return $output;
        }

        // Load the text helper so we can highlight the SQL
        $this->CI->load->helper('text');

        // Key words we want bolded
        $highlight = array('SELECT', 'DISTINCT', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'AND', 'LEFT&nbsp;JOIN', 'ORDER&nbsp;BY', 'GROUP&nbsp;BY', 'LIMIT', 'INSERT', 'INTO', 'VALUES', 'UPDATE', 'OR&nbsp;', 'HAVING', 'OFFSET', 'NOT&nbsp;IN', 'IN', 'LIKE', 'NOT&nbsp;LIKE', 'COUNT', 'MAX', 'MIN', 'ON', 'AS', 'AVG', 'SUM', '(', ')');

        $output  = "\n\n";

        $count = 0;

        foreach ($dbs as $db)
        {
            $count++;

            $hide_queries = (count($db->queries) > $this->_query_toggle_count) ? ' display:none' : '';

            $show_hide_js = '(<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="var s=document.getElementById(\'ci_profiler_queries_db_'.$count.'\').style;s.display=s.display==\'none\'?\'\':\'none\';this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML==\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_hide').'\'?\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_show').'\':\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_hide').'\';">'.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_hide').'</span>)';

            if ($hide_queries != '')
            {
                $show_hide_js = '(<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="var s=document.getElementById(\'ci_profiler_queries_db_'.$count.'\').style;s.display=s.display==\'none\'?\'\':\'none\';this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML==\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_show').'\'?\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_hide').'\':\''.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_show').'\';">'.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_section_show').'</span>)';
            }

            $output .= '<fieldset style="border:1px solid #0000FF;padding:6px 10px 10px 10px;margin:20px 0 20px 0;background-color:#eee">';
            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= '<legend style="color:#0000FF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_database').':&nbsp; '.$db->database.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_queries').': '.count($db->queries).'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$show_hide_js.'</legend>';
            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= "\n\n<table style='width:100%;{$hide_queries}' id='ci_profiler_queries_db_{$count}'>\n";

            if (count($db->queries) == 0)
            {
                $output .= "<tr><td style='width:100%;color:#0000FF;font-weight:normal;background-color:#eee;padding:5px;'>".$this->CI->lang->line('profiler_no_queries')."</td></tr>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($db->queries as $key => $val)
                {
                    $time = number_format($db->query_times[$key], 4);

                    $query = $val;

                    $val = highlight_code($val, ENT_QUOTES);

                    foreach ($highlight as $bold)
                    {
                        $val = str_replace($bold, '<strong>'.$bold.'</strong>', $val);
                    }

                    $output .= "<tr><td style='padding:5px; vertical-align: top;width:1%;color:#900;font-weight:normal;background-color:#ddd;'>".$time."&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style='padding:5px; color:#000;font-weight:normal;background-color:#ddd;vertical-align:top;'>".$val."</td><td style='padding:5px; color:#000;font-weight:normal;background-color:#ddd;'><pre>".print_r($db->query($query)->result_array(), true)."</pre></td></tr>\n";
                }
            }

            $output .= "</table>\n";
            $output .= "</fieldset>";

        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

This is very similar to the original function in the profiler class, what I added was this (+ a change of variable name):

```
<td style='padding:5px; color:#000;font-weight:normal;background-color:#ddd;'><pre>".print_r($db->query($query)->result_array(), true)."</pre></td>
```

By changing this code, you can style how the result appears. Of course, since this is just an extension of the profiler, you need to make sure the profiler is enabled:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

The profiler will then print a new column with the result in it, which looks like this:
[image: profilerextension]

Hopefully this helps!